# Wi-Fi issues with HTC Desire S

Tags: wi-fi

I have an HTC Desire S, which I have had no issues with until now.  It is now not recognising any Wi-Fi networks. When I switch on Wi-Fi it scans, then gives me a green tick telling me it has it but it does not actually bring up any network. I have tried this in various locations so I know it is not an issue with my home router. I have also installed a Wi-Fi management app, and when that did not work I did a full factory reset.

Any help would be gratefully received as I am pulling my hair out now.

Comment: Please check: From your homescreen, tap the menu key, then go to setup, and "wifi & network". There select wifi. Make sure it's enabled (checkbox). Have it scan. Can you see any networks listed up? If so, and yours is there, tap it to connect. What is displayed? Does it ask for your passphrase (provided you have your Wifi protected)? Any error messages?

Comment: Could you install [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat), clear the logs and then try to log on to some wifi and then paste the logs here?

Comment: Basically I went on holiday and when I came back every single wifi network I was logged onto was saying " not in range, remembered" even if I was right next to it. So I cleared them all and started again. Now it will not even see them or it will let me put in the password and try to connect but still comes up with the same message after searching for 5 mins.